# git hooks to enforce JIRA ticket number in commit message

Tags: git

I'm trying to enforce users to add JIRA ticket to git commit.

I used a pre-recieve hook but it is working only after push. I want it to work after commit so if the message format is incorrect, the commit will fail and the user will have the option to edit the commit.

this is my code example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# set this to your active development branch
#develop_branch="master"
#current_branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"

# only check commit messages on main development branch
#[ "$current_branch" != "$develop_branch" ] && exit 0

# regex to validate in commit msg
commit_regex='(#-[0-9]+|merge)'
error_msg="Aborting commit. Your commit message is missing either a JIRA Issue ('#-1111') '"
rm -rf fl.txt
echo $1 >> fl.txt
fil="fl.txt"

if ! grep -iE $commit_regex $fil; then
    echo "$error_msg" >&2
    exit 1
fi
rm -rf fl.txt
```

Comment: If you want the commit to fail, you need a precommit hook. It shouldn't work *after* the commit.

Comment: maybe im missing something. if i will use pre-commit then it will fail the commit and allow the user to edit it ? the only thing that i managed to work is pre-receive. maybe you have a code example for it ?

Comment: Yes, you're writing a pre-receive hook when the behaviour you want fits a pre-commit hook. See the docs on the hooks available: https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Comment: i must have both pre-commit and pre-receive in order the pre-receive to work ?

Comment: What? No. If you want to prevent a commit being made without a JIRA ticket, *you only need a pre-commit hook*. I don't know why you're fixating on pre-receive, which is a server side hook that happens well after the commit has already been made.

Comment: because the pre-commit does not work . maybe you have a code example ?

Comment: Then **give a [mcve] of that**. SO isn't here to write it for you, but if you have a specific issue (*"does not work"* doesn't count) you can get help with it.

Comment: this is my example:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# set this to your active development branch
#develop_branch="master"
#current_branch="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"

# only check commit messages on main development branch
#[ "$current_branch" != "$develop_branch" ] && exit 0

# regex to validate in commit msg
commit_regex='(#-[0-9]+|merge)'
error_msg="Aborting commit. Your commit message is missing either a JIRA Issue ('#-1111') '"
rm -rf fl.txt
echo $1 >> fl.txt
fil="fl.txt"

if ! grep -iE $commit_regex $fil; then
    echo "$error_msg" >&2
    exit 1
fi
rm -rf fl.txt

Comment: **[Edit] the question**, that's unreadable in a comment. Please review the [tour] and [ask] before continuing.

Comment: ...I give up. Best of luck.

Comment: i don't know why you need to be so rude. i added the code to the message as well. if you don't know how to help then you can say that you don't know

Comment: It's not clear why you think I've been rude. I've told you what your question requires, you seem unwilling or unable to provide it, so I'm disinclined to spend more of my free time on this. I won't respond further.

Comment: I think I understand @sarit , He wants a precommit hook as a courtesy to the developers that will remind them to add a ticket number, and a prereceive hook to enforce that they did not bypass teh precommit hook.  At least that is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to get this to work locally by:

1. cd into `<project directory>/.git/hooks/`
2. removing the extension `.sample` from the `commit-msg.sample`
3. open the `commit-msg` file in a text editor
4. copy & paste the following code into that file.

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# An example hook script to check the commit log message.
# Called by "git commit" with one argument, the name of the file
# that has the commit message.  The hook should exit with non-zero
# status after issuing an appropriate message if it wants to stop the
# commit.  The hook is allowed to edit the commit message file.
#
# To enable this hook, rename this file to "commit-msg".

# Uncomment the below to add a Signed-off-by line to the message.
# Doing this in a hook is a bad idea in general, but the prepare-commit-msg
# hook is more suited to it.
#
# SOB=$(git var GIT_AUTHOR_IDENT | sed -n 's/^\(.*>\).*$/Signed-off-by: \1/p')
# grep -qs "^$SOB" "$1" || echo "$SOB" >> "$1"

# This example catches duplicate Signed-off-by lines.

HOOK_FILE=$1
COMMIT_MSG=`head -n1 $HOOK_FILE`
PATTERN="^[A-Z][A-Z0-9]+-[0-9]+"
if [[ ! ${COMMIT_MSG} =~ $PATTERN ]]; then
  echo ""
  echo "    ERROR! Bad commit message. "
  echo "    '$COMMIT_MSG' is missing JIRA Ticket Number."
  echo "    example: 'JIRA-1234: my commit'"
  echo ""
  exit 1
fi
```

afterward, you should be able to see the error upon every attempt to commit a message without a JIRA ticket.

Answer (score 2):

> the only thing that I managed to work is pre-receive

And that is the right approach: you are supposed to enforce a policy (here checking the commit message for a jira ticket number) at the server side (your GitLab server in this instance with a [GitLab custom hook](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/custom_hooks.html#custom-git-hooks)): this is done with a **[server-side hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_server_side_hooks)**.

That means the policy will fail the git push, forcing the user to amend his/her commit and pushing again.

> I must have both pre-commit and pre-receive in order the pre-receive to work ?

No, only a pre-receive hook is needed. Trying to make a pre-commit hook work isn't possible at the server level: you would have to somehow distribute it to all your developers for them to activate it in their own local repo. This isn't practical.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply.
it is not an issue to distribute the hook for the developers, if it will help me make it work :)
pre-receive is working only after pushing but i want the process to fail on commit level so the user will be able to edit his message and commit again

Comment: It actually is very much a distribution issue, because a pre-commit hook has to be activated locally by the developer, and he/she can bypass the hook anyway.

Comment: As opposed to a server-side pre-receive hook, which cannot be bypassed, and which will maybe push fail. So that is the correct approach right there.